# How do I determine properties of the truncation error when multiple series expansions are used in an expression?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I'm given the following expression

$$\displaystyle \frac{a^2}{d^2}\frac{(1-c^2\frac{c}{a})}{(1-b^2)}$$

Each of the letter variables are expanded in a Taylor series. Each series is then truncated at a specified order, for example

$a=O(\delta^2),\quad b=O(\delta^3),\quad c=O(\delta^4),\quad d=O(\alpha^5)$

(note that the variable $d$ is the only term that is a function of $\alpha$...I didn't make a mistake)

How do I determine the **order** $O(\alpha^?,\delta^?)$ **and the leading coefficients** $(?\alpha,?\delta)$ of the truncation error for the given expression?

I'm confused as to how authors in the literature conclude that their final expressions are of a particular order.

Comment: Do you define $x$ and $y$ ? Just out of curiosity.

Comment: No...those are just numbers relative to the formulations given in the papers. I'll edit that to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In principle, you just compute the limit.

\begin{align}
\lim_{\alpha\to 0}\lim_{\delta\to 0}  
\frac{a^2}{d^2}\frac{(1-c^2\frac{c}{a})}{(1-b^2)} &=
\lim_{\alpha\to 0}\frac{1}{d^2}\lim_{\delta\to 0}  
\frac{a^2(1-\frac{c^3}{a})}{(1-b^2)} \\
&=\lim_{\alpha\to 0}\frac{1}{d^2}\lim_{\delta\to 0}a^2  
\lim_{\delta\to 0}\frac{(1-\frac{c^3}{a})}{(1-b^2)} \\
&=\lim_{\alpha\to 0}\frac{1}{d^2}\lim_{\delta\to 0}a^2  
\lim_{\delta\to 0}\frac{(a-{c^3})}{a(1-b^2)} \\
&=\lim_{\alpha\to 0}\frac{1}{d^2}\lim_{\delta\to 0}a^2  
\end{align}

So, you can say
$$\frac{a^2}{d^2}\frac{(1-c^2\frac{c}{a})}{(1-b^2)} \approx C \alpha^{-10}\delta^4$$

To determine the constant $C$, you need more information than merely

$$a=O(\delta^2),\quad b=O(\delta^3),\quad c=O(\delta^4),\quad d=O(\alpha^5)$$

Comment: I know I accepted this answer already @Albe , but can you tell me where $\alpha^{-10}$ comes from? I'm not sure I follow this part.

Comment: You wrote that $d=\mathcal{O}(\alpha^{-5})$, that is $d$ goes to zero at least as $\alpha^{-5}$, so $d^{-2}$ goes to infinity at least as $\alpha^{-10}$. I reckon that writing $\approx$ is not the proper simbol and should interpreted as "decays at least" and "grows at least".

Comment: Sorry @Albe, I ment to ask about $\delta^4$...I'm not sure why I asked about $\alpha$ as it's almost trivial. Thanks for getting back to me though. I appreciate it!

Comment: OK...I see it now. Correct me if I'm wrong, but you're just plugging in the values to the final limit expression. Sorry @Albe....one of those "duh" moments : )

Comment: @ThatsRightJack: Thats right jack ^_^, don't worry